# Passing a spinner value from one fragment to the next

Tags: java, android

I need to get the value of the spinner set in the first fragment and pass the value along to fragment 2. At the moment I'm just trying to set one text field in fragment 2 to the spinner's value, but later on I'll need to somehow have the fragment 1 spinner value match a unit like meters, and then for fragment 2 to be able to take that unit and a user input to then convert it into a second chosen user input.

In fragment 2 I have just typed out some 'bad' psuedo code to showcase what I'm trying to do:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_page1));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_page2));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new
                TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
        });



    }
```

Fragment 1

```
public class Page1Fragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1_fragment, container, false);


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



        return view;

    }
```

Fragment 2

```
public class Page2Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_fragment, container, false);
        fragment1Spinner = Page1Fragment.getSpinnerValue

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       text.setText(fragment1Spinner);

        return view;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) to easily access data from all Fragments (or anything really) using the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) software principle.